# Best approach to switch between TabBarController and ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have been trying an app with initial login screen which then takes to a `TabBarController`.
I want to know whats the best approach to do this any example code would be appreciated. I have tried it but I am unable to switch from `ViewController` to `TabController`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that this is the best way to do it, but it's quick and dirty and works. Present a modal view controller inside your `applicationDidFinishLaunchineWithOptions:` method. You should replace the `@selector` with something more appropriate to what you want to do. Background color is for effect only.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    UIViewController *viewController1 = [[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *viewController2 = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    self.tabBarController.viewControllers = @[viewController1, viewController2];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;


    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];


    // ***** The relevant code *****
    UIViewController *viewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController];
    [[viewController view] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    UIButton *dismissButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [dismissButton setFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 300, 44)];
    [dismissButton setTitle:@"Dismiss" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [dismissButton addTarget:[self tabBarController] action:@selector(dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [[viewController view] addSubview:dismissButton];
    [[self tabBarController] presentViewController:navigationController animated:NO completion:nil];

    return YES;
}
```

I normally wouldn't like to put this sort of code in the app delegate, but if it's a one-time thing like login details, maybe it's ok.

[image]

Comment: how to dismiss the viewcontroller once login is over ? thats the main issue i have, i have tried pushing viewcontroller to the navigation controller from rootviewcontroller but i m unable to switch back to tab bar. Your solution is okay but how to switch back to tabbarcontroller ?

Comment: If you present it modally, you call `dismissViewController:animated:completion:` on the view controller that presented it. In this case, call it on the tab bar controller.

Comment: Exactly thanks and that worked flawlessly, same question has been asked earlier but none has perfect answer like this. hats off.

Answer (score 1):

Assume your root view controller is also your login view.

Now from your root view controller, you can present the tab bar controller a number of ways. One way is to just call the `presentViewController` method from the root view controller.

#### Setup

From within the root view controller, sometime before presenting the tab bar, set it up:

```
myTabBarViewController = [[MyTabBarViewController alloc] init];
[myTabBarViewController setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFullScreen];
[myTabBarViewController setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal];
[myTabBarViewController setRootTabBarDelegate:self];
```

#### Presentation

When you are ready to present, just call this:

```
[self presentViewController:myTabBarViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

#### Notes

The view controller hierarchy looks like this:

```
AppDelegate
  L RootViewController
      L MyTabBarController
```